# Is it possible to obtain file size using WSO2 ESB File Connector version 2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is it possible to obtain file size using WSO2 ESB File Connector functions (e.g. File.Search and File.Move)?  Version of the File Connector in use is 2.0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK a function for getting the file size is not currently available in FileConnector V2 (you can refer to [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+the+File+Connector+Version+2)). Please raise a [jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA) if you feel this should be added in the next releases.

But if you are using VFS with ESB instead of using the FileConnector you can get the file size using the FILE_LENGTH property.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  Yes, in my case, I need to utilize FileConnector so things can be data driven.  I will raise a jira for this feature.  Thanks.

Comment: I meant database driven.